# Jumping to the end of a word in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Using ctrl+arrow keys lets you navigate quickly between typed words. However, ctrl+right moves the cursor to the beginning of the next word rather than the end of the current word, which I very frequently want. In VS Code [you seem to be able to change this behaviour](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34457), but I haven't found an equivalent for the regular Visual Studio. The only workaround I found is ctrl+W to select a whole word, and then pressing right arrow. This is not very intuitive, however. Does anyone have a better solution? An extension maybe?

Comment: Asking for a recommendation on an extension is unfortunately going to be off topic here on Stack Overflow so I would focus on asking about how to configure Visual Studio for this, and if it is even possible.

Comment: I was predominantly asking for a solution in general. The solution might be an extension, or a configuration setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested, I have now created an extension for Visual Studio that provides the desired Edit.WordNextEnd command family. Grab it here, if you want:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Seickelberg.JumpToEndOfWord100

Update: As of July 2019 it supports Visual Studio 2017 *and above*.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. It may be worth mentioning that when using this extension via Tools.Options.Environment.Keyboard the most appropriate choice for "Use new shortcut in" may be "Text Editor" rather than "Global". Incidentally the [VsVim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaredParMSFT.VsVim) extension also features some end-of-word functionality and much more besides, but this is neat and self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Ctrl+Right</kbd> keybinding in VS is bound to the `Edit.WordNext` command.  There isn't an `Edit.WordEnd` command or similar as in VS Code (though there are DocumentEnd and LineEnd).

As suggested in the comments, the quickest way to get this would be to write an extension for it.  You could also suggest this as a feature for VS, and let the editor team decide if it meets their bar as a new feature to add.

Answer (score 3):

In Vscode, for navigating to the end of the next word, you can do `Alt + Right Arrow` in windows and `option + Right Arrow` in MAC.

**Before** `Alt + Right Arrow` or `option + Right Arrow`

```
|Button
```

**After** `Alt + Right Arrow` or `option + Right Arrow`

```
Button|
```

Similarly, You can do `Alt + Left Arrow` or `option + Left Arrow` for navigating to the beginning of the current word.

If you want to navigate to the beginning/end of the **current line** then you do `ctrl + Right Arrow` /`ctrl + Left Arrow` for windows and `cmd + Right Arrow` / `cmd + Left Arrow` for MAC

**Before** `cmd + Right Arrow` or `ctrl + Right Arrow`

```
|import React from "react";
```

**After** `cmd + Right Arrow` or `ctrl + Right Arrow`

```
import React from "react";|
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this question specifically asks for a solution for Visual Studio and not for VS Code.

Comment: oh, my bad. Didn't fully see the question :(

Answer (score 3):

Using Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 (I don't have other versions to test), you can get to the end of the current word using ctrl+F3,right.
Note that this will also set your current search-text to that word.